# Saving data in Internal Storage from Fragments?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

Ok. I finish a app using Navigation drawer and each item on the List opens a new activity.
I always hated Fragments but now I think Fragments is what I need. I want to use Fragments instead of making new Activity. But there comes the problem.

I am not able to save the Data in the internal Storage in Fragments. In activity it is not a problem. I have no Idea why? Even the Toast is not working. Any Idea?

```
public class PagesFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

        public PagesFragment(){}
        Button save;
        EditText filename, entry, pass;
        String FILENAME, JOUR, PASSWORD;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);
            save = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.b5);

            filename = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            entry = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            pass = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText2);


            return rootView;    

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FILENAME = filename.getText().toString();

            JOUR = entry.getText().toString();

            PASSWORD = pass.getText().toString();

            if (PASSWORD.contentEquals("") || JOUR.contentEquals("")
                    || FILENAME.contentEquals("")) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All field required.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                String usernametext = "Username:\n";
                String passwordtext = "Password:\n";
                String space = "\n";

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME,
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fos.write(usernametext.getBytes());
                    fos.write(JOUR.getBytes());
                    fos.write(space.getBytes());
                    fos.write(passwordtext.getBytes());
                    fos.write(PASSWORD.getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your Credentials are saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();




                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I get problems on the toast. It says The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type PagesFragment(this is a class) and on openFileOutPut also the same problem.

I have seen solutions on this websites but my problem is, if the get rid of all the errors also it will not work. I click the button and nothing happens. No toast is displayed and no data are saved.

I just wanted to see if clicking the button will display the toast, so I commented everything and just left the toast there. But when I click the button it doesn't even show the toast. I mean `onClick` is not even working.

PS. If anyone know any tutorial on saving and retrieving data from different fragments, Please put the link below. That would be really helpful. Thanks.

LogCat:

```
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.PagesFragment.onCreateView(PagesFragment.java:32)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
02-28 12:46:43.957: E/AndroidRuntime(9022):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly Solved this question.

```
            save = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.b5);
            filename = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            entry = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            pass = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

In this lines, I replaced `getActivity()` with `rootView` as the function was returning `rootView`.

I also added

```
save.setOnClickListener(this);
```

On this line

```
 FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME,
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I added `getActivity()`, so it becomes,

```
FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(FILENAME,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

It works now. Thanks @Shrikant for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getApplicationContext, try to use getActivity() for fragments to display the toast.
And for button click use btn.setOnClickListener(this).

Comment: What about the ´openFileOutput´?

Comment: I open the app and Open the the above Fragment and the app crashes. When I comment out save.setOnClickListener(this); The Fragment opens but the button doesnot work.

Comment: please post your logcat in the question, put this save.setOnClickListener(ClassName.this) in your onCreateView method

Comment: save.setOnClickListener(ClassName.this) still crashes!! I replaced ClassName.this with my class name from above code that is PagesFragment.this

Comment: Are you sure your button is in fragment_pages.xml file??

Comment: I have put the download link to the source code in the question. It would be really helpful if you yourself build the project. thanks.